# Compiling on Ubuntu 12.04 using older glibc version

Tags: compiling, glibc

I am doinng an Operating Systems course where we need to compile a program on Ubuntu 9.10. This program is not running as expected on laterer releases of Ubuntu (such as 12.04)

My question is, how can I compile a C program using the kernel of 9.10 on Ubuntu 12.04 (the newest release)

I've installed an Ubuntu 9.10 partition on my computer so I can use the libraries from there. but, nevertheless, I would like to work from my 12.04 partition.

Maybe [this manual](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-6.html) could help?

Answer (score 4):

You'd be best off creating a "chroot" for Ubuntu 9.10, and compiling within that chroot.

There's some detail about this in my answer to [Building multiple packages for deployment on different Ubuntu versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103995/building-multiple-packages-for-deployment-on-different-ubuntu-versions/104010#104010), but the basic procedure is:

- Use `mk-sbuild --name=my-karmic-chroot karmic` to create a new chroot for Ubuntu 9.10 (the codename for 9.10 is "karmic")
- Use `schroot -c my-karmic-chroot` to enter the new chroot, and do your compiling

If you're compiling Ubuntu packages, the `sbuild` tool can be used to automate this.

Note that this does not use the **kernel** of 9.10, only the userspace components (including libc and C runtime libraries). You'll still be running the 12.04 kernel. However, do you specifically need the 9.10 kernel?

If you really do need the 9.10 kernel, you can use `virt-manager` to setup a 9.10 virtual machine on your 12.04 install. You can then log into this like it's a real 9.10 machine.

Comment: but I will like to follow the instructions found in the link Ive shown earlier.
even simpler, I can replace the gcc option -nostdinc explained in the link with --sysroot=my_ubuntu_9.10_partition then I hope it would compile with the 9.10 glibc libraries\includes

Comment: You could do that, but a chroot is "cleaner"; for more complex projects, there may be other system dependencies that aren't controlled by gcc's sysroot configuration. eg, stuff that uses `pkg-config`.